# How to find out what process calls out-of-proc COM object?

Tags: com

Assume that break point hit in method of COM object in out-of-proc server (EXE). The call is synchronous and client(another process) that invoked COM object method still waits for HRESULT. How to find out what process (client) called above mentioned method of COM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following article MSDN claims that goal can be achieved (article is  large, therefor I will not copy it here)
[Identifying the Caller From the Server Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550898(v=vs.85).aspx)

In short - MSDN suggests using **DbgRpc** tool from "Debugging Tools for Windows" or WinDbg and its RPC extension (command **!rpcexts.getcallinfo  0 0 FFFF 970** where 970 is hex PID)

I repeated all steps but without success - I encountered problems that I described in separate Stackoverflow question:
[problems-using-dbgrpc-on-windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204672/problems-using-dbgrpc-on-windows7)